# Is $Tf$ $\mu$- measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measurable-functions, product-measure

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are sets with measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined
on them. 
Suppose $K(x, y)$ is $\mu × \nu$ measurable and that there is a
constant $C > 0$ such that
$\int_{X}|K(x, y)| dµ(x) ≤ C$ for $\nu$ a.e. $y$.

If $f$ is a
measurable function on $Y$ , let $Tf$ be the function on $X$ defined by
$Tf(x) = \int_{Y}
K(x, y)f(y) dν(y)$.

Is  $Tf$  $\mu$ measurable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure we don't need more on $f$, like $f\in L^1(d\nu)$? For instance take $X=Y=[-1,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, $K(x,y)=1$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\chi_{x\neq 0}$, then $Tf(x)$ would be $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{y}dy$ that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TommasoSeneci No more conditions are given.

Comment: Then I would say no, since as you see above in general $Tf$ is not even well defined